# Different Wordpress Gallery Thumbnail sizes for Mobile and Desktop?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

Is there a way of using the built in Wordpress Gallery function and have different sized thumbnails for mobile and desktop. At the moment I am using Media Queries to determine viewport size and deliver a different stylesheet but I can't figure out how to determine what thumbnail size to show for mobile and desktop?

Any tips?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what did you try actually ? What is your theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the original image size, you will be fine scaling it as a percentage width of the available viewport. 
Are you planning on delivering a completely different experience for your mobile users?
You seem to be already using the correct technique